# Understanding the GROUP attribute in MapServer's CLUSTER object?

Tags: mapserver

I am trying to use the `GROUP` function in MapServer's `CLUSTER` object.

We have a cluster defined where when we have a lot of objects on top of each other we group them in a cluster.  Show a circle and a count.  However the cluster is made up of two types of locations.  And we would like to see two numbers (a number for each type) in the cluster representation.  We were trying to use Group for this but have not had any luck and cannot find an example.

Comment: According to http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Clustering-based-on-a-classified-column-td4227600.html `The GROUP setting specifies which features may belong to the same cluster `,  so it's probably not what you need.